# show some post on page if page_id is 3 else show some different post

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

i am using page.php only which is default template for pages in wordpress, my header footer and sidebar are same on all pages but main area content is changing which i want wordpress to pull for each specific page. for example if page is about us ..it should show posts of about us category and so on...

---

i want to know if i can achieve this with conditional statements or i have to make separate templates for each page.

i tried something like ...

```
<?php if (page_id ==11 ):
 // post loop to display all fetch all post of category id 4
  $page_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&cat=4'); ?>
<?php  while ($page_query->have_posts()) :
 $page_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
} ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile;  endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

this is my loop on page.php but it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

wow... not sure if this helps, but is much neater and cleaner than what you have currently

```
<?php
if (page_id == 11){
   $page_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&cat=4');
    while ($page_query->have_posts()){
        $page_query->the_post();
        echo "<a href=/"". the_permalink() ."/" rel=/"bookmark/"><".the_title()."</a>";
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        }
        the_content();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Still, you're unclear of what does not work, so it's hard to tell what isn't working...

Comment: thanx for the cleaner version :D but i guess i am clear of what i want ...show post of some category if page id is some "id"..i meant before displaying post on page loop should check the page id and display posts accordingly..

Comment: yeah, but I do not use WP and I fail to see where you are actually using page_id or 11, both of which are used in your initial if statement. I'm guessing your problem is within your WP_Query

Comment: in wordpress all pages by default use page.php as template and page_id the id of the page on which i want to show result of this condition loop...

Comment: maybe ... i only want to ensure that the result of this loop should not display on every page ..but only on the page whose page_id is 11.

Comment: then you need to fix your WP_Query. Everything else is fine, just your query needs tweaking

Comment: The query looks fine to me, what is the current output on the page with ID 11, what is displayed on every other page?

Answer (score 0):

I see this has never been resolved and I had nothing to do so I hope this will help someone in the near future.

If you want to show posts that are in relation to the page "about us" you should name that categorie the name of the page. By doing so you you can change to code above to the following:

```
    global $post;
    $pagename = get_the_title($post->ID);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => $pagename,
    );
    $page_query = new WP_Query($args);
         while ( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post();?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php the_title()?>
                </a>
             <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                     the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                }
                the_content();

          endwhile;
```